# What temperature is needed for carbon monoxide to reduce iron oxide?

Tags: redox

What temperature is needed for carbon monoxide to reduce iron oxide?
That is at what temperature the following reaction will take place:
Fe2O3 + CO -> Fe + CO2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an experiment, carbon monoxide dose reduce iron oxide at 1200°C (2192°F).

But probably, this is not the minimal necessary temperature.
A better answer is still welcome.